# How to make constraint value of a column for the same value of other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, unique-constraint, mysql-5.7

```
TABLE 1 (photos)
photo_id | student_id | main_photo
----------------------------------
1        | 1          | 0
2        | 1          | 1
3        | 2          | 1
4        | 1          | 0
```

I need to make sure that for the same student_id, there is only one main photo. Thus, the value of `1` must be only one and cannot be two or more (for the same student_id), but the value of `0` can be multiple (more than one).

MySQL version: 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the atbe with a UNIQUE constarint, and you see the result below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE photos (
>   `photo_id` INTEGER,
>   `student_id` INTEGER,
>   `main_photo` INTEGER
> );
> ALTER TABLE photos
> ADD CONSTRAINT UC_student_id UNIQUE (student_id);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '0')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', '1', '1')
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '2', '1')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM photos
> ```
>
> ```
> photo_id | student_id | main_photo
> -------: | ---------: | ---------:
>        1 |          1 |          0
>        3 |          2 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0b1a9e3456b0a9a1f1adf6b1e8dde62)*

For your purpose, you can use BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER, that can check main_photo =1

> ```
> CREATE TABLE photos (
>   `photo_id` INTEGER,
>   `student_id` INTEGER,
>   `main_photo` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> #DELIMITER $$
>
> CREATE TRIGGER before_photos_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON photos FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM photos WHERE `main_photo` = 1 AND `student_id` = NEW.`student_id`) THEN
>       SIGNAL sqlstate '45002' set message_text = 'mainphoto already exsits';
>     END IF; 
>
> END ;
> #$$
> #DELIMITER ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '0')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', '1', '1')
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', '2', '1')
> ```

> ```
>   INSERT INTO photos
>   (`photo_id`, `student_id`, `main_photo`)
> VALUES
>   ('4', '1', '1')
> ```
>
> ```
> mainphoto already exsits
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM photos
> ```
>
> ```
> photo_id | student_id | main_photo
> -------: | ---------: | ---------:
>        1 |          1 |          0
>        2 |          1 |          1
>        3 |          2 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=98e40aef58b6ac9b5df4e15714c2b007)*

Comment: I don't need constraint for the `student_id`. But I do need constraint for `main_photo` when the value is `1`.

Comment: For that you need a BEFORE INBSERT TRIGGER see changed answer

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is a filtered unique index.  Alas, MySQL does not allow that.

Instead, you can use a trick with a generated column:

```
alter table photos add main_photo_null int generated always as
 (nullif(main_photo, 0));
```

Then you can use this in a unique constraint:

```
create unique index unq_photos_main on photos(student_id, main_photo_null);
```

MySQL allows multiple values for `NULL` in a unique index/constraint, so the uniqueness is not enforced when the `main_photo` value is `0`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3c924a13ea868f3247637dc6c4f85138) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Using MySQL 5.7, I got error #1064 when altering the table.

Comment: @user1801605 . . . MySQL has supported generated columns starting with version 5.7.10:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html.

Comment: @user1801605 . . . I added a db<>fiddle as well.

Answer (score 2):

In very recent MySQL version, you can use a `case` expression in a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_photos_uniq 
    on photos((case when main_photo then student_id end));
```

This enforces uniqueness of `student_id` on rows where `main_photo` is logically true (this actually assumes that this is a boolean column - otherwise you might want `when main_photo = 1` instead).

**[Demo on dB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c9b8c9638aae27eb972b4ef73da4a212)**:

```
create table photos (
    photo_id int auto_increment primary key,
    student_id int,
    main_photo int
);

create unique index idx_photos_uniq 
    on photos((case when main_photo then student_id end));


insert into photos (student_id, main_photo) values (1, 1);
insert into photos (student_id, main_photo) values (1, 0);
insert into photos (student_id, main_photo) values (2, 1);
insert into photos (student_id, main_photo) values (1, 0);
-- ok

insert into photos (student_id, main_photo) values (1, 1);
-- error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'photos.idx_photos_uniq'
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7 and got error #1064 when creating the unique index.

Comment: @user1801605: 5.7 does not qualify as a *very recent version*. I think my solution requires version 8.0.13.